# Group by for list in list

Tags: c#, linq, list, group-by

I have list of Issues : `List<Issue>` where `Issue` is class :

```
public class Issue : BaseEntity
{
    private string m_KeyString;

    [JsonProperty("expand")]
    public string Expand { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    #region Special key solution
    [JsonProperty("key")]
    public string ProxyKey
    {
        get
        {
            return Key.ToString();
        }
        set
        {
            m_KeyString = value;
        }
    }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public IssueKey Key
    {
        get
        {
            return IssueKey.Parse(m_KeyString);
        }
    }
    #endregion Special key solution

    [JsonProperty("fields")]
    public Fields Fields { get; set; }
}
```

Class `Fields` looks like this :

```
public class Fields
{
    [JsonProperty("summary")]
    public string Summary { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("assignee")]
    public Assignee Assignee { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("worklog")]
    public List<WorkLog> WorkLogs { get; set; }
}
```

And class `WorkLog`:

```
public class WorkLog : BaseEntity
{
    [JsonProperty("updateAuthor")]
    public string Author { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("timeSpent")]
    public string TimeSpent { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("timeSpentSeconds")]
    public int TimeSpentSeconds { get; set; }
}
```

I want to get on output `Author - SUM (TimeSpentSeconds)`

So i need to group by `Author` and then get `SUM`.

For each item in `Issues` list I make this :

```
var sumTime = issue.Fields.WorkLogs.GroupBy(x => x.Author).Select(x => new
{
    User = x.Key.Name,
    Amount = x.Sum(s => s.TimeSpentSeconds)
});
```

which group by user and count sum.

But how can i manage the same not just for one item in list but for all list?

Comment: loop through and add them in a list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I think you're saying that you can run this query for a single `Issue`, but you want to be able to run it over all the items in a `List<Issue>`.

I'm assuming that you don't want to break it out separately by `Issue`, so what I'd do is this:

```
List<Issue> issues = // get Issues from wherever
var sumTime = issues.SelectMany(issue => issue.Fields.WorkLogs)
               .GroupBy(x => x.Author)
               .Select( x => new
               {
                    x.Key.Name, 
                    Amount = x.Sum(s => s.TimeSpentSeconds)
               }
               );
```

### Disclaimer:

this was done entirely from memory, with no testing.

Comment: looks like it works but result is the same as with loop - users are not grouped. Seems like after group in Issue, i should also group in collection?

Comment: nope... it's my fault... group by Author - it's bad idea... cause Author is class. Better is grouping by Author.Name